# WPF Toolkit Data Visualization - How To Set Interval, Minimum and Maximum In Code-Behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

First my xaml

```
<charting:Chart x:Name="ChartMain" />
```

And here is my Code behind:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> valueList1 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
valueList1.Insert(0, new KeyValuePair<string, int>(DateTime.Now.ToString(), 1));

LineSeries lineSeries1 = new LineSeries();
lineSeries1.Title = "Eins";
lineSeries1.DependentValuePath = "Value";
lineSeries1.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
lineSeries1.ItemsSource = valueList1;
ChartMain.Series.Add(lineSeries1);
```

My question: how can i set the Minimum / Maximum and the Interval in code behind?

Comment: Look at `ChartMain.Axes`. Do you see any axes available in that collection?

Comment: Yes I do. Example:
   LinearAxis lx = new LinearAxis();
   lx.Minimum = -1;
   lx.Maximum = +1;
   lx.Interval = 0.5;

   ChartMain.Axes.Add(lx);

But I can't see ist on the Chart after compiling...

Comment: oh, sorry, one line is missing:
lx.Orientation = AxisOrientation.Y;
And now it works, fine - I thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> valueList1 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
valueList1.Insert(0, new KeyValuePair<string, int>(DateTime.Now.ToString(), 1));

LineSeries lineSeries1 = new LineSeries();
lineSeries1.Title = "Eins";
lineSeries1.DependentValuePath = "Value";
lineSeries1.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
lineSeries1.ItemsSource = valueList1;
ChartMain.Series.Add(lineSeries1);

LinearAxis linearAxis = new LinearAxis();
linearAxis.Orientation = AxisOrientation.Y;
linearAxis.Minimum = 0;
linearAxis.Maximum = +1;
linearAxis.Interval = 0.1;

ChartMain.Axes.Add(linearAxis);
```

Comment: I would use `KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>` and `DateTimeAxis` instead.

Comment: `KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>` sounds really good! But do I need Two Axes? One for `AxisOrientation.X` (DateTime) and one for `AxisOrientation.Y` (Value) ?

Comment: Not really, you can just do exactly what you have done so far, just replacing `LinearAxis` with `DateTimeAxis`.

Comment: And what about the `AxisOrientation.X;`? In my example: `AxisOrientation.Y;`